# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') on google cloud storage

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

```js
  import { Storage, File, Bucket } from '@google-cloud/storage';
  const Zip = require('zip-bucket');
    
    
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucket = storage.bucket('bucket_name');
  const zipper = Zip(storage);

  const zipResult = await zipper({
    fromBucket: 'bucket_name',
    fromPath: `folder_name/`,
    toBucket: 'bucket_name',
    toPath: `new_file_name.zip`,
  });
```

Destination bucket and source bucket is same.
I am trying to zip all the files in folder in cloud storage and save the file in the same bucket.

Here is error on google cloud run logs

[image]

Comment: Add debugging code to verify you can read the bucket contents using the object `bucket`. You might have a permission problem.

Comment: If you can share the entire code with where reading length that would be great to understand the issue.Make sure you have initialized GCP in your project properly.
Make sure that the variable is initialized and not null.
Check the format of that variable you read property length.